# Mapping function across its arguments

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation

Is there a more elegant way to do the following? (The code should be `f`-less and replacement-less)

```
expr = f[a, b, c];
Head@# /@ List @@ # &@expr
```

---

```
{f[a], f[b], f[c]}
```

If it were a list of arguments then elegant solution would be:

```
expr = f[{a, b, c}];
Thread[expr]
```

---

```
{f[a], f[b], f[c]}
```

But that is not the case. My expression is `f[a, b, c]` not `f[{a, b, c}]`.

The shortest code I found was `f /@ List @@ expr` but this contains `f` which I want to be avoided.

Comment: `Replace[head_[args___] :> head /@ {args}] @ expr` is about as elegant as I think it'll get. It's not exactly as standard transformation you encounter regularly.

Comment: It is nice, l like it. But I have just added that the code should be without any replacements.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
Tuples[expr, 1]

(* {f[a], f[b], f[c]} *)
```

Comment: Wow, I did not expect `Tuples` can be used this way. I guess nobody can beat you answer.

Comment: The same code but in one character shorter form: `expr~Tuples~1`.

Answer (score 12):

Using `Subsets`:

```
expr = f[a, b, c];

Subsets[expr, {1}]

(*{f[a], f[b], f[c]}*)
```

Or using `Subsequences`:

```
Subsequences[expr, {1}]

(*{f[a], f[b], f[c]}*)
```

Or using `Outer` and `Level`:

```
Level[Outer[Head@#, #, 1], {1}] &@expr

(*{f[a], f[b], f[c]}*)
```

Or using `Outer` and `Cases`:

```
Cases[Outer[Head@#, #, 1] &@expr, s1_@s2_]

(*{f[a], f[b], f[c]}*)
```

Answer (score 11):

```
Operate[Map[#]@*List &, expr]
```

Answer (score 9):

Some alternatives:

```
f[a, b, c] // #[[0]] /@ Level[#, 1] &

(* {f[a], f[b], f[c]} *)

f[a, b, c] // #[[0]] /@ List @@ # &

(* {f[a], f[b], f[c]} *)
```

Sharper, not shorter:

```
f[a, b, c] // #[[0]] /@ ({##} & @@ #) &

(* {f[a], f[b], f[c]} *)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
expr[[0]]/@{Delete[0][expr]}

(* {f[a],f[b],f[c]} *)
```

or

```
Thread[Head[expr][{Delete[expr,0]}]]

 (* {f[a],f[b],f[c]} *)

Thread[Head[expr][{Sequence@@expr}]]

(* {f[a],f[b],f[c]} *)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
expr = f[a, b, c];
```

Using `BlockMap`

```
BlockMap[# &, expr, 1]
```

Using `Partition`

```
List @@ Partition[expr, 1]
```

Using `Span`

```
Array[expr[[# ;; #]] &, Length@expr]
```

All of them give:

> `{f[a], f[b], f[c]}`

Answer (score 6):

````
expr = f[a, b, c];

expr[[0]] /@ (expr[[#]] & /@ Range[Length[expr]])
 (* {f[a], f[b], f[c]} *)

Take[expr, {#}] & /@ Range[Length[expr]]
 (* {f[a], f[b], f[c]} *)

Array[expr[[0]][expr[[#]]] &, Length[expr]]
 (* {f[a], f[b], f[c]} *)
```
````

Answer (score 4):

```
expr = f[a, b, c];

expr[[0]] /@ List @@ expr
```

{f[a], f[b], f[c]}

```
First @ Cases[expr, x_[y__] :> x /@ {y}, {0}]
```

{f[a], f[b], f[c]}

```
expr /. x_[y__] :> x /@ {y}
```

{f[a], f[b], f[c]}

Answer (score 3):

```
Thread[f[a, b, c] /. y_[x__] -> y[{x}]]
```

??

Answer (score 3):

```
Permutations[expr,{1}]
```

Or :

```
expr~Permutations~{1}
```

*{f[a], f[b], f[c]}*

Answer (score 1):

**Using `TakeList`:**

```
expr = f[a, b, c];

TakeList[expr, ConstantArray[1, Length@expr]]
```

> {f[a], f[b], f[c]}

---

Other thoughts:

```
TakeList[expr, {1, 2}]
```

> {f[a], f[b, c]}

Comment: The one with `TakeList` is not correct.

Comment: Why so, may I ask? @azerbajdzan

Comment: Your output is `{f[a], f[b, c]}` not `{f[a], f[b], f[c]}`. Easy to overlook I guess...

Comment: Read the post from the beginning, please. The second one is listed under `Other thoughts`. @azerbajdzan